# Imported object shows aligned to the wrong axis

Tags: objects, add-on, import, snapping

I was doing fine with importing an obj I made in Marvelous Designer into Blender for rigging.  The dress would settle nicely on my SL avi.

Now when I import the object; it is perpendicular to my avi and I have spent a week trying to figure out what I did...  Is there a keystroke or setting that I need to make sure is correct so that my dress fits my avatar again?

[image: Import Not going to Avi]

Answer (score 5):

Most import/export types have an option to alter the Forward and Up alignment. Try some different options to find which one matches your exported data.

[image: import options]